# Capture Active Window with Keyboard SendKeys

Tags: vb.net, image, keyboard-events

After experiencing problems with Visual Basic's printform quality, I have decided to take a different approach.  I am going to simulate an ALT-PRINTSCREEN keyboard key-press to capture the form in its current state.

However, before this happens, I need to remove certain elements from the form (such as the border), and after getting the image, I need to replace these elements.  I am having some timing/synchronization problems with this, as I am noticing that certain elements are still on the image that has been copied to the clipboard.

I figured this was due to the fact that it takes time to process the changes, and time for Windows to process the simulated "send keys", so I set up sleep timers.  I am having mixed results.  I notice that if I don't replace the elements afterwords, the clipboard image appears correctly.  However, if I do replace them, even if I set up a 20 second sleep timer, they do not appear.

Therefore, I know there is some sort of synchronization problem, but I am not sure how to fix it.  Here is the code I am using:

```
        'Make these forms invisble so they are not printed
    Logo.Visible = False
    MenuStrip1.Visible = False
    ReportsButton.Visible = False
    pnlmain.BorderStyle = 0 'remove the border

    'Sleep
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    'simulate an ALT and PRINTSCREEN key click to get ONLY the report
    SendKeys.Send("%{PRTSC}")

    'Sleep
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    'Now, get the image from the clipboard
    Dim formImage As System.Drawing.Image
    formImage = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage()

    Logo.Visible = True
    MenuStrip1.Visible = True
    ReportsButton.Visible = True
    pnlmain.BorderStyle = 1
```

Changing the sleep durations does not seem to change much (unless they are very low).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: here is the code for draw to bitmap (after modifying the code above):

```
formImage = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height, Me.CreateGraphics())
Me.DrawToBitmap(formImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))
```

When it is sent to the print action:

```
Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics

    'transform the form image so it fits the height and width of the paper, with a 5 px margin
    Dim res = printSettings.PrinterResolutions
    Dim newSizeDestinationPoints As Point() = {
        New Point(5, 5),
        New Point(841, 5),
        New Point(5, 956)
    } 'These values are based on A4 sized paper

    'g.DrawImage(formImage, 5, 5)
    g.DrawImage(formImage, newSizeDestinationPoints)
```

The low quality is not coming from the stretch.

Comment: All that those Thread.Sleep() calls do is make your UI thread go catatonic. So it can't repaint anything.  Use a real Timer.  Or simply call Update() to force the paint.

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back here.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Time to ditch the approach and to google "vb.net how to make a screenshot".

Comment: Yes, I've done this already.  As I specified in the original post, I have experienced quality problems with VB's print form feature, which is why I am taking this approach now.

Comment: None of the top hits I see mention PrintForm.  Hmm, odd isn't it?

Comment: Have you seen [**`DrawToBitmap()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)? It will synchronously draw the form onto an image. Thus you can make the necessary changes to the UI, call `Me.DrawToBitmap(...)` and then revert the changes again.

Comment: I'll give that a try, and see how it goes.  Thank's for the suggestion.

Comment: I have implemented the DrawToBitmap().  The quality is a major improvement over that of the PrintForm.Print(Me), when I was using that, but it is still somewhat problematic.  When I use the keyboard shortcut during my own tests, or use the snip tool, the quality is as it should be.  Do you have any suggestions as to how to improve the quality to that of the keyboard shortcut or snip tool?

Comment: The quality should be the same since it is drawn to a bitmap (_Bitmap_ is an uncompressed image format). May I see how you use `DrawToBitmap()` and perhaps an example of the quality difference?

Comment: Yes, I've added the code to the original question post at the bottom.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not seeing this, I didn't receive a notification from your latest comment. -- Other than that you should remove the `Me.CreateGraphics()` parameter, making your call: `formImage = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)` I don't see any problems... The quality should be fine. What does it look like if you use the same code to draw the resized image on another bitmap, then save that to a file? (Create a new `Bitmap` of a large enough size, then create your graphics via: `Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(yourNewBitmap)`)

Comment: When I try your suggestion, everything looks good.  It seems that the problem lies in sending it to the printer, perhaps.

Comment: I'm not very into printing stuff via code, but many printers aren't that good when it comes to printing images. Check the printer settings or try another printer (if possible) if you think the quality is worse than it should be. You could also try printing the image from a different program to see if there's any difference.